# Whats the best way to move AI? LibGDX - PONG game

Tags: java, libgdx, physics, collision

currently in the middle of making a Pong game. i want the player2 paddle (computer) to follow the ball left to right depending on where the ball is. I have this

```
position.x = position.x + playerVectorX;    

        if(ballPong.getPosition().x < position.x){
            System.out.println("left");
            playerVectorX *=-1;
        }

        if(ballPong.getPosition().x > position.x){
            System.out.println("right");
            playerVectorX *=-1;
        }
```

I guessed this would be right but i was wrong. the paddle just goes left to right very quickly within a short distance.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just go with

```
position.x = ballPong.getPosition().x;
```

?

Comment: Would that not make the game impossible for the human player?

Comment: because like @jdphenix said i dont want to make it impossible. i want it to move slowly to the ball in the x direction. And hopefully be able to add power ups/downs where the computer gets faster or slower and ball gets smaller :))

Comment: OK got it. First, use delta. I don't use libgdx, but every game making library has it. `position.x += delta_in_sec * PlayerVectorX`. And then when the ball is near player set PlayerVectorX = 0;

Comment: Selfish plug:http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/57352/imperfect-pong-ai/57376#57376

Comment: Perfect. i thankyou :))))) i wonder why that works but using just the playerVectorX doesnt ? ?

Comment: Because game is drawn and updated more then once per second. Think it like in real life: you have speed, distance and time. Distance = time * speed. In you case distance is position.x, speed is PlayerVectorX and time is delta.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that every time it needs to go right, it changes the direction. What you should do is something like this:

```
position.x = position.x + playerVectorX;    

    if(ballPong.getPosition().x < position.x){
        System.out.println("left");
        playerVectorX = Math.abs(playerVectorX);
    }

    if(ballPong.getPosition().x > position.x){
        System.out.println("right");
        playerVectorX = Math.abs(playerVectorX) * -1;
    }
```

Hope that helps!